# how can i use consumePurchase method in in-app billing v3

Tags: java, android-studio, in-app-billing, google-play-console

I am using in-app billing from this link: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3
it allows me to purchase the item one time only. so I googled how to be able to purchase it more than one time all results lead that I need to consume the old purchase. I cannot find how and were to call the consuming function
here is the consuming function:
billingProcess.consumePurchase(n_Selected)

I tried to call it in the onCreate method: it did not do anything
I tried to call it in onProductPurchased method: it did not do anything

Answer (score 2):

You should consider Google Play's official Billing Library. Add
com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0
to your build.gradle.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive_v2
is Google's best practice.

You should always call queryPurchases and call consumeAsyc for outstanding purchases in the callback. Also, call consumeAsyc in onPurchasesUpdate method, which is triggered after a successful purchase.